# Firebase NormalizedCollection white screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a Firebase normalized collection to collect and merge data for a user's conversations and the individual conversation page itself.
When referencing "conversations" from the controller(inside an `ng-repeat`) I get a blank screen. That is, until I manipulate the DOM by dragging around. On mobile, the page stays blank.

I've stripped the ng-repeat down to:

```
<div ng-repeat="conversation in conversations">
      <p>{{ conversation }} </p>
</div>
```

And in the controller I create the normalized collection as stated in the Firebase documents as well as copy/pasted from the generator:

```
var baseRef = new Firebase("https://firebasesubdomain.firebaseio.com");
var norm = new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
  [baseRef.child('/profile/' + authData.uid + '/conversations'), "usersConversations"],
  baseRef.child("/conversations")
);

norm = norm.select(
  "usersConversations.$key",
  {"key":"conversations.$value","alias":"conversation"}
);

var ref = norm.ref();

ref.once('value', function(snap) {
  $scope.conversations = snap.val();
});
```

Does anyone have an idea why this would cause a blank page?

Comment: Debug info? Console logs?

Comment: No console errors. I'd be glad to capture to logs at any point in the code if it will help.

Comment: Is there a way to wait for a loaded state so I can resolve this and inject it into the controller? Such as: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDp5LYPFm8Y&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKkg55tSHz0Xc8ZMVS1GJQL&index=1